# cómo capturar fecha en un procedimiento almacenado en sql server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Este es mi procedimiento:

```
--creacion procedimiento
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_in_Cty

(@Name VARCHAR(20),
 @Date datetime )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO city (Name_City,Datte) VALUES(@Name,@Date)
END

--Ejecución del procedimiento:
EXEC Sp_in_Cty 'Atlantico','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
```

Al ejecutar me muestra este error:

> Mens 8114, Nivel 16, Estado 5, Procedimiento Sp_in_Cty, Línea 0
>   Error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a datetime.

Comment: La variable @Date que envías al Store Procedure es del tipo Varchar, pero esta correctamente escrita como para convertirla en Date?

Comment: Debes convertir el current_timestamp a varchar

Comment: Si vas a insertar siempre la fecha actual quizás no tenga sentido poner el parámetro.

Answer (score 2):

Si la columna **Datte** en la tabla **City** es del tipo Date, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
EXEC Sp_in_Cty 'Atlantico', getdate();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder pero esa consulta ya la intente y no funciono

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en que a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP le estas poniendo ''

```
EXEC Sp_in_Cty 'Atlantico',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create procedure Inser_Cty(
    @Name varchar(20),
    @Date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO city (Name_City,Datte) VALUES(@Name,@Date);
END;

GO

declare @Date datetime = current_timestamp

execute Inser_Cty 'Atlantico', @Date;

select * from city;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de tu lógica: digamos que si quieres grabar la fecha del sistema en todos tus registros te recomiendo que te dirigas al editor de tabla y coloques por defecto `current_timestamp` en la propiedad *valores por defecto* de la tabla de tal manera que en tu procedimiento ya no coloques el campo *dato* y lo dejes por defecto, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consultauser9
@IdAud int,
@IdSis int,
@IdUser int,
@CiUser VARCHAR(10),
@Response VARCHAR(10),
@Mesage VARCHAR(20) 
AS 
INSERT INTO dbo.AdAudit([IdAud],[IdSis],[IdUser],[CipUser],[Response],[Mesage])
VALUES (@IdAud,@IdSis,@IdUser,@CiUser,@Response,@Mesage) 
GO

EXEC consultauser9 '11','2','3','3484136','true','USUARIO_CADUCADO';
```

Answer (score -2):

```
create proc sp_fecha_desactivar_empleado @EmpleadoId int as update Empleado set Fecha=CONVERT(date,GETDATE(),103) where EmpleadoId=@EmpleadoId go
```

Comment: Apenas conozco SQL. Explica como esto resuelve la pregunta.

Comment: @Martin, edité la pregunta desde la cola de revisión, pues el sistema la detecta como de muy baja calidad, por su extensión. No quise votar por su borrado para no afectar tu record, pero si creo que está haciendo falta añadir una explicación de como esto resuelve el problema del AP. Por favor lee [answer]. Un saludo.